# Disable password hashing for particular users

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

We are using a single table for both admin and normal users. We need to save the admin password in hash format, but save the user password in plain text. How do do that with CakePHP 3.0

**EDITED**:
User's username and password are used as a login credentials on another site as API. So i need to save password without hashing method of cakephp 3.0

Comment: There is literally no reason on this planet for saving any users passwords in plain text. do not do it.

Comment: we need that, coz that password use to access the api

Comment: That makes as much sense as: I must drive my car with no brakes because it has to go faster than 5 miles per hour. Plus, if you "need" that there's something wrong with your app design, like using a user's password as an api auth token.

Comment: You don't need to save the passwords as plain text. Unless by "we have to" you mean "we really want to steal our users passwords".

Comment: please make sure to tell us what application / website you are building so we can all stay well away from ever using it. thanks.

Comment: If you are storing external passwords (like for an api or email) then either a) you should confirm if service has token based access, like oauth, or b) if it doesn't, store the passwords encrypted but reversible using something like blowfish. And store the key in encrypted form and on separate system from the encrypted passwords.

Comment: Passwords should **never** be stored as plain text. Perhaps you can expand on what API you are using that requires passwords in your question.

Comment: Updated the question so pls check that

Comment: @all Also i use user's credentials on API only not on the cakephp side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out serveral times to you in the comments you should never store passwords as plain text in your database. This is regardless to whether or not they are being directly used by your app or not. As Anthony mentioned in his comment to your question you should consider storing encrypted passwords encrypted that can be reversed by your app.

You should also check that the API you are using does not provide a more secure method for logging in using access tokens.

If you want to persist with storing plain text passwords despite all this then you should consider storing them in a separate column to your hashed ones. For example:-

```
id | username | password | api_login_password
```

It would not be a good idea to mix the usage of the `password` column by having some records with encrypted passwords and others not.

Using a schema like this you will not need to hash the `api_login_password` but continue to hash the app's passwords. Presumably you have CakePHP setup to hash the passwords on your User entity, this will not affect the `api_login_password` column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `beforeSave` method.

// in model

```
function beforeSave()
{
    // put the conditions here

return true;
}
```